# can i rebuild sound code in Windows

Tags: android, android-source

i download AlarmClock in the sound code  of android,i have modified it,but i want to run it

can  i  rebuild AlarmClock in Windows, if i can ,how? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the android platform code MUST be built on a linux (or Mac). See the [download instructions](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) for the build requirements for the android platform. On a side note to this, you have to download the entire android platform, you cannot just pull down "AlarmClock" and build it, it requires classes and objects defined in other parts of the platform.

Comment: You could use vmware and a linux image though, see this blog post: http://blog.mathiaslin.com/building-android-system-and-kernel-on-windows

Comment: Yes, you can, and I would recommend that if you don't plan on using linux for more then just building the code anyhow, but you still are building in linux, not windows. VirtualBox from Sun/Oracle works well too. http://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you need to heavily patch things that are not exposed in the SDK but are actually present in the rest of the Android source code. This may mean you might lose a lot of functionality that is dependent on private stuff in the Android source, and the only way around that is to refer to Ryan Conrad's answer.